# Passing Tuple model to MVC grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tuple view model contains list of Version and list of User.This tuple value I have to pass it to MVC grid.

Index.cshtml Page

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Version>,IEnumerable<user>>
@Html.Grid(Model.Item1.AsEnumerable()).Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Add(c => c.VersionId).Titled("Version Id");
   columns.Add(c => c.VersionName).Titled("Version Name").Filterable(true);
   columns.Add(c => c.Description).Titled("Description");
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true)
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
      {
        List<version> versionList = null;
        List<user> userList = null;
        versionList = _settingsRepo.GetVersionList();
        userList = _settingsRepo.GetUserList();
        var tuple = Tuple.Create<List<version>, List<user>>(versionList, 
        userList);
        return View(tuple);
      }
```

Facing error " 'Version' does not contain a definition for 'VersionId' and no extension method 'VersionId' accepting a first argument of type 'Version' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) " at line  columns.Add(c => c.VersionId).Titled("Version Id") in Index.cshtml page.

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo, but `var tuple = Tuple.Create<List<*v*ersion> ...` doesn't match `@model Tuple<IEnumerable<*V*ersion>,IEnumerable<user>>` Note the lower and upper case v on version

Comment: Yeahh you are right. In view I have binded some other predefined class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your view you have

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Version>,IEnumerable<user>>
```

whereas your controller is defined as

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create<List<version>, List<user>>(versionList, 
    userList);
```

Update the view to use the lower case version class

Comment: @Html.Grid(Model.Item1.AsEnumerable()).Columns(columns =>
          {
          columns.Add(c => c.VersionId).Titled("Version Id");
            columns.Add(c => c.VersionName).Titled("Version 
         Name").Filterable(true);
          columns.Add(c => c.Description).Titled("Description");
         }).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true);      How I can add Id attribute to @Html.Grid.

Comment: Is this so you can use Javascript?  If so, take a look at https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20side%20%28javascript%29&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Yes I am using the same. I need to do nested grid rows in @html.grid.Here how can pass the  values for child grid.Can you help me out in this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multipile%20grids%20on%20the%20page&referringTitle=Documentation - I am not sure if this tool allows you do what you want it to do